# Cisco Monitor Destination Port

Tags: cisco, cisco-ios

Using the command of session monitor on CISCO 3750 switch:

monitor session 1 destination interface fastethernet */*

Can we redirect the needed traffic to an interface which is already having live traffic for a live service? or the destination port must not be used by live services?

thks in advance.

Comment: This is not about programming. It is off topic and should be deleted.

Comment: You should use this site https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

Simple,  use **Wireshark**, but instead of using your Fast Ethernet as a destination port, use it as a source for the .pcap File

1. Download Wireshark
2. telnet or ssh into your switch
3. monitor session 1 source fastethernet (port you wish to sniff traffic on)
4. monitor session 1 destination fastethernet (your port connected to your end device)
5. If done correctly, your current term should freeze, don't freak out just open a new term.
6. Open Up wireshark
7. Disable and re-enable your network adapter for a refresh of network packets

You'll be able to see all traffic currently running on your desired interface, you can use any capture, but Cisco recommends Wireshark since its used by most network analysts and easier to use and a strong community to support your Wireshark questions as well :)

Answer (score 0):

You will be able to use these stats to monitor your port interface :

- Use monitoring Application like as **`Wireshark`**
- You could use top talker command in Cisco IOS command line to see live traffic of your interface
- At the end and best one is running **`NetFlow`** on your Cisco IOS device and check live traffic.

NetFlow with [manageEngine](https://www.manageengine.com/products/netflow/cisco-netflow.html?network=g&device=c&keyword=%2Bcisco%2Bios%2Bnetflow&campaignid=1652449678&creative=318172428130&matchtype=b&adposition=1t1&placement=&adgroup=61859086765&targetid=kwd-616861703204&location=2840&gclid=CjwKCAjw7anqBRALEiwAgvGgm4QMs0w2j7rWuI_UZT-S04pzu9jaOWuMO9rVT1CtuJrplSCcZz9zIhoCH2kQAvD_BwE)

NetFlow Analyzer [ManageEngine](https://www.manageengine.com/products/netflow/?network=g&device=c&keyword=netflow&campaignid=1642380406&creative=326698632919&matchtype=p&adposition=1t3&placement=&adgroup=66165255795&targetid=kwd-301009861608&location=2840&gclid=CjwKCAjw7anqBRALEiwAgvGgm22Sytjeu6MniEX23o_3MTFiHC-Q8G01gEhaZjB8Cg0kwzdBfTNm4hoCvEEQAvD_BwE)

NetFlow with [SlorWinds](https://try.solarwinds.com/lp/network-traffic-analyzer?&CMP=KNC-TAD-GGL-SW_NA_X_PP_CPC_LD_EN_PBRDE_DWA-X-945268740~46582886546_g_c_netflow%20solarwinds-e~256725142237~~&ds_cid=71700000047357273&ds_agid=58700004758934834&network=g&device=c&keyword=Netflow%20solarwinds&matchtype=e&creative=256725142237&feeditemid=&gclid=CjwKCAjw7anqBRALEiwAgvGgm9GvFYuBsNWQsOUJGNL5cyoMIzaO1FbA2bRwVbqbOTrSRZl__RlxTBoCLS4QAvD_BwE)

NetFlow Analyzer [SolarWinds](https://www.solarwinds.com/netflow-traffic-analyzer)